# Postmark - Cleaning parsed email

Tags: python, json, parsing, email

I want my customers to be able to reply by email. I'm looking at incoming email parsers such as postmark but they seem to include all nested replies and additional header information in the email, not just the new content.

As of now I use this approach:

```
clean_index = text.find('Respond by replying to this message above this line.')
if clean_index != -1 and clean_index > 1:
    new_text = text[:clean_index]
else:
    new_text = text
return new_text
```

However, every email client seems to do something different when replying to emails. For example hotmail adds this markup above the previous email when you hit reply:

```
My typed new message......
From: test@hotmail.com
To: q3vxif_e+lj9p@inbound.test.com
Subject: RE: hhj - test
Date: Sat, 26 Apr 2014 16:42:51 +0100
Respond by replying to this message above this line.
```

This means reply has all this extra rubbish in it, instead of just the message itself.

**Question**
My question is, when it comes to isolating the new message in an email, is there any "one-size-fits-all" approach to removing all other useless information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no one-size-fits-all approach for this. Mostly because of the very issue you pointed out - each provider (MUA in this case) follows their own format.

You could borrow from existing open source projects which handle similar situations. Github allows people to reply to issues via email, and they open sourced the [code for the parser](https://github.com/github/email_reply_parser).

(Gitlab [doesn't yet](http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/3805212-reply-by-email).)

Answer (score 0):

Postmark app now supports reply parsing. Parsed content is in **StrippedTextReply** property.

Limitations from Postmark documentation:

> The StrippedTextReply field is limited to English text replies and is
>   currently tested on the following email platforms: Yahoo, iCloud,
>   Gmail, Outlook.com, iOS Mail, Apple Mail, Microsoft Outlook (Windows &
>   Mac), and Mozilla Thunderbird. Postmark makes a 'best attempt' to
>   parse all inbound replies.

Check it out [here](http://blog.postmarkapp.com/post/89958626773/a-collection-of-inbound-updates)